# Need Sql query for case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table datatable

```
ID   Task Response by   Created   
1    mark               2015-03-01 3:02:44 PM
2    harry              2015-03-02 3:06:22 PM
3    alex               2015-03-01 3:14:02 PM
4    jim                2015-03-30 3:18:33 PM
5    jim                2015-03-30 3:24:49 PM
6    alex               2015-03-30 3:34:35 PM
```

Now I want to count total of task response by week and output like

```
week    mark  harry  alex  jim 
1        1      1     2     2
```

names of task response by are n number

Comment: So, what did you do?

Comment: Have a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: datatable or database table ??? is week will come based on your last date

Comment: i have excatly couldn't understand why week is 1 when it comes as march month

Answer (score 1):

i have given result set basing on your output but exactly can't assume about week result when you have march month (they will give 10 and 14 )

```
declare @t table (Id int,Task varchar(20),created date)
insert into @t (Id,Task,created)values (1,'mark','2015-01-01 3:02:44 PM'),
(2,'harry','2015-01-01 3:02:44 PM'),
(3,'alex','2015-01-01 3:02:44 PM'),
(4,'jim','2015-01-01 3:02:44 PM'),
(5,'jim','2015-01-01 3:02:44 PM'),
(6,'alex','2015-01-01 3:02:44 PM')

;with CTE as(
SELECT [mark],[harry],[alex],[jim],created  FROM (
Select [mark],[harry],[alex],[jim],created from (
Select A.Id,A.Task,A.created,COUNT(A.RN)OVER(PARTITION BY TASK )R from (select ID,Task,created,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY task order by task desc)RN from @t
GROUP BY ID,Task,created)A)B
PIVOT(MAX(R)FOR Task IN ([mark],[harry],[alex],[jim]))P)V


GROUP BY [mark],[harry],[alex],[jim],created)
select DATEPART(week,created)Week,MIN(mark)[mark],MIN(harry)[harry],MIN(alex)[alex],MIN(jim)[jim] FROM CTE 
GROUP BY created
```